# How to choose a color from colorpicker in Behat?

Tags: drupal-7, behat, color-picker

So I have this colorpicker in a Drupal instance and I need to write an autotest in Behat to pick a color and ensure that the HTML is of the form:

```
<div style="color:#13456;">Testing</div>
```

Is there a default Behat step like 'I want to pick "#13456" from colorpicker'?
I am also open to using Selenium web driver in Behat to write steps like 'I drag the colorpicker pointer towards "top" "right"' or something like that.

Can anybody please throw some light on this so I can proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `evaluateScript` with a jQuery script like this:

```
jQuery('#colorpickerHolder').ColorPickerSetColor('#612828');
```

Create a step for this to select the color, then save the color and check it in another step.

Comment: This appears to be promising @lauda, thanks! I shall try this and mark as answer if it works!